# Xarray plot not working when I call plot()

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray, satellite-image

I'm very new to Xarray, up until now I have been doing all of my remote sensing analysis in R.

I'm working with netcdf files of Sentinel 5P air pollution data. I've regrid the data and reduced the file size using the harp package. Now, I want to see what a single plot looks like using Xarray. However, my plots all show up as white, and I have no idea why.

```
os.chdir("/Users/priyapatel/OneDrive/python/Greece")
ncfiles = glob.glob('./*.nc')
ncfiles[1]

'./S5P_OFFL_L3__NO2____20210721T223233_20210722T001403_19544_02_020200_20210723T153147.nc'


ds_disk = xr.open_dataset(ncfiles[3], decode_times=False)
ds_disk
```

[image]

```
no2 = ds_disk.tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density
no2.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there are any valid data? `no2.notnull().any()`?